# Alphabets or Text filling effect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am developing a site for my client and he asked me to have the same below site  kind a effect for his website

http://www.big.dk/

here you can see text is filling up and after it finish filling all the letters, homepage loads up. any idea how can I copy the same kind a effect or any code you can share. I try to rip the code but I think the site is  using `swf` file not `jquery` as I couldn't rip it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect mentioned, I followed the following approach.

1. Create an image with required text on it (`StackOverflow` for example).
2. Make the text on this image transparent. (I did it in `Microsoft Powerpoint`).

This is how the image looks

[image]

Note that the text area is **transparent**. Download this image and open it in any image viewer to verify.

3. Then, Create a [gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). (You can use [this](http://angrytools.com/gradient/) for simplicity)

Combining the above resources, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5z1dttw/).

```css
#color {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 130px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000 0%, #2AA830 25%, #05C1FF 50%, #ffff00 75%, #0808BF 100%);
  /* ff3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #ff0000), color-stop(25%, #2AA830), color-stop(50%, #05C1FF), color-stop(75%, #ffff00), color-stop(100%, #0808BF));
  /* safari4+,chrome */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000 0%, #2AA830 25%, #05C1FF 50%, #ffff00 75%, #0808BF 100%);
  /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000 0%, #2AA830 25%, #05C1FF 50%, #ffff00 75%, #0808BF 100%);
  /* opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000 0%, #2AA830 25%, #05C1FF 50%, #ffff00 75%, #0808BF 100%);
  /* ie10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 0%, #2AA830 25%, #05C1FF 50%, #ffff00 75%, #0808BF 100%);
  /* w3c */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0808BF', GradientType=1);
  /* ie6-9 */
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 130px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/plKV4.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  background: gray;
  animation: slide forwards 5s linear;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="color">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

I have used [`keyframes animation`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to fill the color.
It can be easily replaced by `jQuery`